# C++ std::map: get the key at a specific offset

Tags: c++, stdmap

If the keys of my map are dynamically generated, is there a way to get a key value at a specific offset, like the key value of the second key-value pair? I was trying to get a random key value of a map, so I just generated a random number and want to extract the corresponding key with this offset. I don't whether it's the way to achieve that. Or is there a normal method? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like XY problem, why do you need a map if you access by offset?

Comment: I don't know whether is there any other way to get a random key value, maybe not accessing by offset? But I think I have to use map in my case.

Comment: A map is sorted by key, so the offsets of things can change as you add more items. It's possible this is the wrong container for you. A vector of pairs or structs might be more useful if you need easy random access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

```
std::map<int, int> myMap;
auto itAtOffset = std::next(myMap.begin(), offset);
```

If you do not have C++ 11, you can use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) instead.

```
std::map<int, int> myMap;
std::map<int, int>::iterator itAtOffset = myMap.begin();
std::advance(itAtOffset, offset);
```

Note that the complexity is O(N), so if you want faster method, you should consider storing the data in different structure.